# Fill object in Javascript with expected properties

Tags: javascript

I have a prototype

```
class Animal() {
    constructor(name, weight) {
        this.name = name
        this.weight = weight
    }
}
```

and some coming object, which contains these properties plus something else

```
const obj = {
    name: "name",
    weight: 5,
    someRedundantProp: "bla"
}
```

I really enjoy JS mapping with **Object.assign** which would generically create an object for me with all properties, but here I want to fill this new object only with essential fields. 
Surely, I can map this object like

```
new Animal(obj.name, obj.weight)
```

but if at some point I would introduce new properties I will have to change code here, what I don't want to.

Is there some better way?

Comment: `constructor(obj) { this.name = obj.name; ...`

Comment: _"but here I want to fill this new object only with essential fields"_ - then _define_ what "essential fields" are. Are they the actual properties the Animal class already "possesses"? Then declare them properly, so that you can loop over them (starting with .hasOwnProperty) to then pick out the input object properties of the same name you'd like to "copy over"

Comment: @CBroe, essential are fields which constructor expects

Comment: @JJJ, it can be actually :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @JJJ, I can use the way you proposed

Comment: Well, I'm glad that solved your problem.

Comment: _"essential are fields which constructor expects"_ - don't think there is a way to know which ones those are, unless you want to get into parsing actual source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the first argument is an object and then assign the object to this.

But be warned, this has some nasty side effects too.

```js
class Animal {
  constructor( obj ) {
    // Create an object that holds all available options
    const defaultOptions = {
      name: '',
      weight: 0,
    };
    
    // Go over all available options
    Object.keys( defaultOptions ).forEach( key => {
      // Check if obj has key, otherwise use default option
      this[ key ] = obj[ key ] || defaultOptions[ key ];
    } );
  }
}

const obj = {
  name: "name",
  weight: 5,
  someRedundantProp: "bla"
}

const a = new Animal( obj );
console.log( a );
```

Comment: well, in this case it will contain all properties, isn't it? including someRedundantProp

Comment: Yes. Oh sorry, do you only want to allow certain properties? If so, there might be another good solution available too

Comment: I updated my answer. It only takes valid properties now.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(obj) {
        const defaultFields = {
            name: "",
            weight: 0
        }
        Object.keys(defaultFields).forEach(key => defaultFields[key] = obj[key]);
        Object.assign(this, defaultFields);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `reduce` looks a little bit of an overkill :) Why not just using `forEach` and assigning the fields directly instead?

Comment: is there a point in creating **expectedFields** instead of using **Object.keys**

Comment: @VladHatko Where are those keys specified?

Comment: I mean, compared to my answer, without rewriting constructor

Answer (score 0):

I came to this solution for now

```
let animal = new Animal()
Object.keys(animal).forEach(field => animal[field] = obj[field])
```